# Deploy Client Side JARs to Redis?

Tags: redis

We are evaluating the various Distributed Caching solutions available in the market. Our prime focus currently is on Redis and Hazelcast. However, there is one of the major features which we need and that is the capability to deploy client side JARs into the Distributed Cache.

I have been googling since morning to see if such features are available in either Hazelcast or Redis. I found that Hazelcast provides the capability to [deploy client side JARs](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#client-user-code-deployment-beta), but this is still in beta and expected to release with v4.1 of Hazelcast.

However, I couldn't find any such capability from Redis yet. Does Redis or any client side library (like Redisson, Jedis, etc) offer this kind of capability? I looked through Redis documentation and the two client side libraries, Redisson and Jedis, but I couldn't really figure out anything like this.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What are you trying to run on Redis? what does this Jar do?

Comment: One of the teams in our company has a use case where they want to push JARs to Distributed Cache which would basically contain the code that would enable them to perform operations on the other data structures within the cache which they rely on. From what I understood so far is that, firstly, these JARs would be shared across multiple teams, secondly, this will also enable faster computing time for them, since the computing would occur within the cache node as compared to traditional way of fetching the data from Cache and doing processing on the client machine.

Comment: You should check https://redisgears.io the next version should support JVM

Comment: Can you point me to the list of upcoming and planned features in redisgears?

Comment: https://github.com/RedisGears/RedisGears/issues

Comment: Since, these changes to support JVM under progress, one thing that I wanted to understand is that whether or the capability would include pushing an entire JAR? I see that for Python the support includes capability to run an entire Python script within Redis.

Comment: Yes it will support entire Jar

Comment: Is there any ETA on this feature yet?

Comment: As per the documentation for RedisGears `It is a dynamic framework for the execution of functions that, in turn, implement data flows in Redis, while (almost) entirely abstracting the data's distribution and choice of deployment (i.e. stand-alone vs. cluster, OSS vs. Enterprise)`. So, does it mean that the inability of current transaction mechanisms to operate upon data which is stored in different hash-slots is overcome by RedisGears? Also, its says `almost`, so, what's the restriction?

Comment: Let's move to the repo forum

Comment: https://forum.redislabs.com/c/modules/

Comment: Let me post a query there then.